# elasticsearch reindexing to different index has different no of documnts

Tags: elasticsearch

i am trying to re-index an existing index to some other index. ex. index all documents from index `A` to index `B`. index B has new mapping .but when i look for number of documents in both indexes its very much different i am getting an approx difference of 19000 documents.what could be the reason for it.here in the re-indexing code:

The nuber of documents in `index B` happens to be 19000 less than the documents in `index A`.

```
POST /_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "A"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "B"
  }
}
```

***EDIT: i needed to remove a type from an existing index and add some new types to that index .below are the steps that i performed.***

steps to remove an existing type from index and add new type to it

1. remove all data from a `type` of `index A`
2. download new data to `index A`
3. create `index B` and update it mapping (latest mapping for new
   data)
4. reindex from original `index A` to new `index B`
5. remove original `index A` -
6. create the original `index A` with updated mapping
7. reindex from `index B` to `index A`

Comment: can you share mappings for both indexes?

Comment: i wish i could but due to some restrictions(official) i cannot :( because its very properiatery. the mappping for new index (to which i was reindexing) has only additions to the old mapping.i am updating the question regarding step i did. as needed to remove an existing type from an index and some new types to that index.

Comment: @user3775217 i have updated my question with why i needed to reindex along with the steps i took